# Navigation Bar Alpha Value not setting in iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, ios7

This issue is only occurring for `iOS 7.x`, the same code works fine in `iOS 6.x`.

In my application, I have set the `navigationBar's alpha value` as `0.0f` in  `viewWillAppear` method for `ViewController-A`.

When I push to this `viewController` everything seems to work fine.

Suppose now from this `viewController-A`(with navigation bar alpha set as `0.0f`), the app goes to background.

When the app returns to the foreground again(with `viewControllerA` as the visible controller) then the `navigation bar alpha value` changes to `1.0f` on its own.

I tried registering for the `UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification` notification in my view controller & set the alpha to 0.0f again.

But even then the bar retains alpha value 1.0f when returning from background.

Has anyone else faced this issue?

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: So do you actually want to hide uinavigationbar by doing alpha 0.0

Comment: I want to use alpha value instead of hiding it using 'navigationBarHidden'.

Comment: How about setting the color of the Navigation bar as clearcolor

[self.navigationController.navigationBar setTintColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

Comment: Using clear color will not make the navigationBar alpha value 0.0f.

Answer (score 0):

The question is: what do you want to achieve? You can make the bar translucent if you want to, or change it's tint. Changing the alpha is not too easy. You could fiddle with the subviews of the controller's UINavigationBar, but I'd refrain from that.

Hiding of BAR is only the best way .

Answer (score 0):

i think you can do this by using below code, set the bartint color and alpha.

```
[self.navigationBar setBarTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:125/255.0 green:178/255.0 blue:15/255.0 alpha:0.2]];
```